# How to configure apache2 for django wsgi?

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

i was trying to run my django application using apache2 and i failed. Its giving me a 500 internal server error saying
`The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

First i created a **firstweb.wsgi** file in my home directory. And put this codes

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/var/www/firstweb'] + sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODELE'] = 'firstweb.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` i created a file named **firstweb.conf**
In firstweb.conf i have this code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nihan/firstweb.wsgi

ServerName firstweb.com
Alias /static /var/www/firstweb/static

<Directory /var/www/firstweb/ >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my `/var/www/` i created a django project by typing

```
sudo django-admin.py startproject firstweb
```

This is the first time i am trying apache , mod_wsgi and Django

Please  help me to understand i have i missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that Apache runs as generally doesn't have access to stuff in your home directory. That this is the case cannot be confirmed as you haven't supplied the error message from the Apache error log, only what was displayed in the browser. Suggest you watch:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

That talk covers common errors like that.